# Not sure why this if statement's "else" fails to work

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup/requests and Tkinter to web scrape stock values off of Yahoo Finances. I set up my program to scrape values if the user types words in the GUI entry box, and everything else should return a "Not Found".

However, there is a problem. My program follows the if statements properly, but with the "else" it fails to update. After spending a while looking through my code, I am not sure why this occurs.

If someone could help me, I would much appreciate it!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import tkinter

headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) Apple Webkit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"}


# *** Functions pertaining to the GUI application ***

# Resets the data fields after submission
def ResetData():
    user_company.delete('0', 'end')

#  *** Functions pertaining to the web scraping of Yahoo Finances ***

def ChooseValue():
    global output_value

    try:
        if user_company.get().upper() == "DOW JONES":
            getDOW()
        elif user_company.get().upper() == "APPLE":
            getApple()
        elif user_company.get().upper() == "NASDAQ":
            getNASDAQ()
        elif user_company.get().upper() == "S&P 500":
            getSP()
        else:
            output_value.config(text = "Not Found!", fg = "green")

    except Exception:
        output_value.config(text = "ERROR!", fg = "red")

    output_value.config(text = "$" + str(value), fg = "blue")
    ResetData()

# Extracts the DOW Jones Industrial Average
def getDOW():
    global value
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^DJI?p=^DJI"
    r = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    value = soup.find("span", class_= "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()

# Exracts NASDAQ index 
def getNASDAQ():
    global value
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^IXIC?p=^IXIC"
    r = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    value = soup.find("span", class_= "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()

# Extracts S&P 500 index
def getSP():
    global value
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^GSPC?p=^GSPC"
    r = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    value = soup.find("span", class_= "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()

# Extracts Apple Inc. (AAPL)
def getApple():
    global value
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL"
    r = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    value = soup.find("span", class_= "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()

def main():
    global user_company, output_value

    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Stock Value Search")

    output_value = tkinter.Label(window, text = "             ", fg = "blue")
    output_value.pack()

    user_company_label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Enter company/index: ")
    user_company_label.pack()

    user_company = tkinter.Entry(window)
    user_company.pack()

    processButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Search", command = ChooseValue)
    processButton.pack()

    window.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: You have a try/except that will hide any error inside it from you. Add a `raise` to the except block for debugging to see if an exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

The second last line of `ChooseValue` overwrites whatever you write in `output_value` on the else case.

Comment: that was supposed to be indented. Silly me! Thanks to you and @IainShelvington

Answer (score 0):

In your `def ChooseValue():` method: the last line is **always** run no matter the result of the if/elif/else block or the try/except block.

```
# This is always run and overwites any previous calls
output_value.config(text = "$" + str(value), fg = "blue")
```

You should add this line to an `else` block for the try/except so that is only run if there is not an exception at least

```
except Exception:
    output_value.config(text = "ERROR!", fg = "red")
else:
    output_value.config(text = "$" + str(value), fg = "blue")
```

If you return from the "Not Found" branch of the if/else block and add the call to `ResetData()` to a finally bloc you should get the behaviour you want

```
 def ChooseValue():
     global output_value

     try:
         if user_company.get().upper() == "DOW JONES":
             getDOW()
         elif user_company.get().upper() == "APPLE":
             getApple()
         elif user_company.get().upper() == "NASDAQ":
             getNASDAQ()
         elif user_company.get().upper() == "S&P 500":
             getSP()
         else:
             print('else run')
             output_value.config(text = "Not Found!", fg = "green")
             return
    except Exception:
        output_value.config(text = "ERROR!", fg = "red")
    else:
        # This only gets executed when an exception is not raised or a return/continue/break is not used
        output_value.config(text = "$" + str(value), fg = "blue")
    finally:
        # Always gets run, even when something "returns"
        ResetData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it run. You can add a print to see it. And you should return in else block.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import tkinter

headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) Apple Webkit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"}


# *** Functions pertaining to the GUI application ***

# Resets the data fields after submission
def ResetData():
    user_company.delete('0', 'end')

#  *** Functions pertaining to the web scraping of Yahoo Finances ***

def ChooseValue():
    global output_value

    try:
        if user_company.get().upper() == "DOW JONES":
            getDOW()
        elif user_company.get().upper() == "APPLE":
            getApple()
        elif user_company.get().upper() == "NASDAQ":
            getNASDAQ()
        elif user_company.get().upper() == "S&P 500":
            getSP()
        else:
            print('else run')
            output_value.config(text = "Not Found!", fg = "green")
            return

    except Exception:
        output_value.config(text = "ERROR!", fg = "red")

    output_value.config(text = "$" + str(value), fg = "blue")
    ResetData()

# Extracts the DOW Jones Industrial Average
def getDOW():
    global value
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^DJI?p=^DJI"
    r = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    value = soup.find("span", class_= "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()

# Exracts NASDAQ index 
def getNASDAQ():
    global value
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^IXIC?p=^IXIC"
    r = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    value = soup.find("span", class_= "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()

# Extracts S&P 500 index
def getSP():
    global value
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^GSPC?p=^GSPC"
    r = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    value = soup.find("span", class_= "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()

# Extracts Apple Inc. (AAPL)
def getApple():
    global value
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL"
    r = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    value = soup.find("span", class_= "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()

def main():
    global user_company, output_value

    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Stock Value Search")

    output_value = tkinter.Label(window, text = "             ", fg = "blue")
    output_value.pack()

    user_company_label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Enter company/index: ")
    user_company_label.pack()

    user_company = tkinter.Entry(window)
    user_company.pack()

    processButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Search", command = ChooseValue)
    processButton.pack()

    window.mainloop()

main()```
````

Answer (score 0):

try converting the `user_company.get().upper()` to string before the `if` statement, and save it to a variable.

Like this:

```
variable = str(user_company.get().upper())
if variable == "DOW JONES":
     getDOW()
elif variable == "APPLE":
     getApple()
elif variable == "NASDAQ":
     getNASDAQ()
elif variable == "S&P 500":
     getSP()
else:
     print('else run')
     output_value.config(text = "Not Found!", fg = "green")
     return
```